# When Jean Gets Slimed By Toad, Are Her Grunts Random?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, toads-spit, x-men-2000

I was wondering this, because when she gets slimed by Toad, she grunts 7 times while trying to pry it off, 7 times when Cyclops finds her, and 3 right before he blasts it off. Is she trying to say anything, yell for help maybe, or are these just random grunts?

Comment: So far, the closest thing I've found was in the comic adaptation for the film. When she gets slimed by Toad, she says, "C-can't breathe. Can't mmmpphh."

Comment: Why are there so many Toad questions here?

Comment: @Taladris-He's become a popular character since 2000

Comment: I stand by my serious doubts that all these Toad spit questions, especially this one, are being asked in good faith.

Comment: @Adamant-Why? It seems you don't like the character and are therefore dismissive of anything related to it

Comment: I have no problem with the character Toad or questions about them. I have a lot of problems with poor-quality questions seemingly asked just to use a particular tag.

Comment: @Adamant they get answers from top users so more rep for both parties and more encouragement for future spitty questions.

Comment: Clearly the grunts aren't random, she makes them for the very specific reason of having been slimed and not being able to breathe or talk. As for the question being tagged *toads-spit*, there is nothing confusing about what Toad and his spit are doing here.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Some people have expressed concern about the seriousness of the question, but the question is by no means unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [original screen directions](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/X-Men.html) just say that she's "*struggling*". Any noises she's making are liable to be the actress trying her best to emulate [Fay Wray](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZk0eYOI4tg&feature=youtu.be&t=46).

> [Cyclops continues to pull on the slime.  Jean's struggles are becoming more panicked].
>
> [Cyclops stops and puts his hands on Jean's shoulders, pinning her down].
>
> **CYCLOPS:** *Jean.  Jean stop.  Stop moving.*
>
> [Jean continues to struggle for a moment.  She starts to calm down, her chest still hitching involuntarily for air].
>
> **CYCLOPS** (cont'd): *Jean, trust me.  Don't move.*

The film's [Official Novelisation](https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_A_Novelization) concurs. She's simply making *general panicked noises*.

> Jean twisted around to discover Toad, facing her head-on. His tongue shot out and struck her face, coating her with a slimy substance that congealed almost instantly.
> He laughed. “Hate to kiss and run.”
> **It took Jean only a moment to realize that she couldn’t breathe. The stuff was blocking her nose and mouth. She clawed at it, fighting to free herself of it.**
> An instant later the metal door that had slammed down on Cyclops melted under the heat of his energy beam. Scott came tearing out, firing at Toad, who dodged out of the way, ricocheting off two walls, gaining the momentum he needed to kick Cyclops back into the room he’d just escaped from.
> Then Storm attacked him, and he rolled over, finding the leverage to knock her up and over the railing into the balcony area.
> Then Cyclops was back, and Toad leaped up and out of sight, also on the balcony.
> Jean was starting to black out. **She dropped to her knees, then to her back, fighting the stuff that clung to her face, her throat, and her nose. It had hardened until it felt like bone, completely blocking her air.**
> “Jean!” Cyclops said, bending over her. “Hold still!”
> He desperately tried to pry it off, but it would not yield.
> **She could feel the blackness coming in around her. She desperately needed air. She fought to keep her eyes open.**
> Finally Cyclops stood. “Jean! Stop moving!”
> She didn’t understand.
> “Stop moving!” he shouted.
> She did as he ordered.

And as you've pointed out, in [the graphic novelisation of the film](https://xmenmovies.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men:_The_Movie_-_Special_Edition), as the slime covers her face, she says...

> *"C-Can't breathe" Can't -:MMMPPHHH"*

... but I suspect that this is intended to be exposition for the reader.

[image: Panel 1: Toad's spit hits Jean in the face she exclaims "M-my face--being covered in slime!". Panel 2: Jean claws at the slime covering her face completely, "C-Can't breathe" Can't -:MMMPPHHH". Panel 3: Toad hides on the dark ceiling as Cyclops smashes the door down with his vision shouting "All right, mister--time for round two!"]